# How to 'make' multiple nodes in ROS to be part of one package?

Tags: ros

I have created two ROS nodes and have compiled them using add_executable command in the "CMakeLists.txt". I have also added them to the launch file that I am running using roslaunch. But when running roslaunch, I get this ERROR: cannot launch node of type [r/r2_detect]: can't locate node [r2_detect] in package [r]

I tried adding catkin_package() to the "CMakeLists.txt" as suggested here: http://answers.ros.org/question/145801/cant-locate-node-in-package/, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you run each node individually?

Comment: Please add your `CMakeLists.txt` (you can edit your question for that). Btw, if you had to add `catkin_package`: I suggest you always use `catkin_create_pkg` to create new ROS packages. This way a CMakeLists.txt is auto-generated that already contains all the ROS related stuff that is necessary (as well as lots of comments).

Comment: Make sure you are sourcing the setup.bash file in your devel folder!